# On Eclipse IDE 2023-03 I cannot see the Mylyn views

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I have installed the Mylyn plugin onto my Eclipse IDE 2023-03 and verified it is installed from the marketplace. I am however not seeing the tasks. The views do not show up in "View -> Show View" menu option either. Any hints on where I went wrong?

I have attached a screenshot of the Show View options. Previously there was an entry for Task List. The 'tasks' that you see in the screenshot open up tasks from the source (for example for '// TODO ...' comments.

I also show the installed software in the second screenshot.

The logs do show errors, notably

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui [763]

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui [763]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui; bundle-version="3.25.2.v20200814-0512"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui [762]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.icu.text
           -> Export-Package: com.ibm.icu.text; bundle-symbolic-name="com.ibm.icu"; bundle-version="72.1.0"; version="0.0.0"
              com.ibm.icu [8]
                No resolution report for the bundle.         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui; bundle-version="3.8.0"; x-installation:="greedy"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui; bundle-version="3.25.2.v20200813-0821"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui [751]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core; bundle-version="3.25.2.v20200813-0821"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core [750]
                       No resolution report for the bundle.                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.icu.text
                  -> Export-Package: com.ibm.icu.text; bundle-symbolic-name="com.ibm.icu"; bundle-version="72.1.0"; version="0.0.0"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed; bundle-version="1.0.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed; bundle-version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [739]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.xml.bind; bundle-version="2.2.0"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: javax.xml.bind; bundle-version="2.2.0.v201105210648"
                     javax.xml.bind [722]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.activation; version="[1.1.0,1.2.0)"
                         -> Export-Package: javax.activation; bundle-symbolic-name="javax.activation"; bundle-version="1.1.0.v201211130549"; version="1.1.0"; vendor="geronimo"
                            javax.activation [721]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.mail; resolution:="optional"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.mail.internet; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.stream
                         -> Export-Package: javax.xml.stream; bundle-symbolic-name="javax.xml.stream"; bundle-version="1.0.1.v201004272200"; version="1.0.1"
                            javax.xml.stream [723]
                              No resolution report for the bundle.                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.xml.bind; bundle-version="2.2.0"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.sun.xml.bind; bundle-version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"
                     com.sun.xml.bind [718]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.sax; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.stax; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.jvnet.fastinfoset; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.jvnet.fastinfoset.stax; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.jvnet.staxex; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.namespace
                         -> Export-Package: javax.xml.namespace; bundle-symbolic-name="javax.xml.stream"; bundle-version="1.0.1.v201004272200"; version="1.0.1"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.stream
                         -> Export-Package: javax.xml.stream; bundle-symbolic-name="javax.xml.stream"; bundle-version="1.0.1.v201004272200"; version="1.0.1"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.stream.events
                         -> Export-Package: javax.xml.stream.events; bundle-symbolic-name="javax.xml.stream"; bundle-version="1.0.1.v201004272200"; version="1.0.1"
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses constraint violation.
  org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.bind' from resources javax.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.2.0.v201105210648"; osgi.identity="javax.xml.bind"] and jakarta.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="jakarta.xml.bind"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=javax.xml.bind)(bundle-version>=2.2.0))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: javax.xml.bind
  javax.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.2.0.v201105210648"; osgi.identity="javax.xml.bind"]

Chain 2:
  org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=com.sun.xml.bind)(bundle-version>=2.2.0))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.wiring.bundle="com.sun.xml.bind"
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.api
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.api)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.api; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime; uses:=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime)(&(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime; uses:=javax.xml.bind
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind)(&(version>=2.3.3)(!(version>=2.3.4))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.bind
  jakarta.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20221203-1659"; osgi.identity="jakarta.xml.bind"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1852)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have now downloaded IDE 2023-05 and Mylyn works perfectly.

Comment: Please show what you have in _Window > Show View > Other..._ (I don't know what you mean by _View > Show View_) and that Mylyn is installed: _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ (there are different Mylyn plugins). Anything in the error log (please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_)?

Comment: Does it work with the nightly build of Mylyn (_Help > Install New Software..._ working with the update site [`https://ci.eclipse.org/mylyn/job/GitHub-mylyn-Orga/job/org.eclipse.mylyn/job/main/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.mylyn-site/target/repository/`](https://ci.eclipse.org/mylyn/job/GitHub-mylyn-Orga/job/org.eclipse.mylyn/job/main/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.mylyn-site/target/repository/))?

Comment: @howlger Your hint to show the error logs (I didn't know this was available) in Eclipse itself is showing some errors, I will post once I have  review them,

Comment: @howlger, had the same issue and using the nightly build worked for me

Comment: @Simon Thanks for verifying. If you find issues, please report it [here](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/issues). [In Eclipse 2023-06 Mylyn will be back](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg19654.html), so things will become better.